# can I save my upload images in assets folder before sending to server in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

In angular 4 When I'm uploading a image to server from angular forms I need to store it in assets folder.

Is it possible? or we need to move the image file server?

Comment: You've to write server-side code. Angular is client side.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of action is related to you server side angular may set the file by you api but it 's not possible for angular to have access to your files so you have to deal with saving the file to assest folder by server side.

Happy coding

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the path of Assets folder from Server side